# Side bearings of Minion Pro quotes

Tags: fontspec

I'm using Minion Pro with XeLaTeX. However, quotes are much too tight. I know the MinionPro package, for use with LaTeX, has a loosequotes option which slightly increases the side bearings of the ‘quote’ character.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to do the same with fontspec — and how to do it?

Thanks in advance